# libhdfs - cannot open shared library libhdfs.so.0.0.0.0

Tags: c, hadoop, hdfs, shared-libraries, libhdfs

I have a running hdfs instance, as evidenced by -

```
reikdas@reikdas-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-dh1xxx:~$ jps
16083 Jps
12389 NameNode
12774 SecondaryNameNode
11083
```

and

```
reikdas@reikdas-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-dh1xxx:~$ hadoop fs -ls /
2021-09-27 12:06:59,520 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - reikdas supergroup          0 2021-09-27 00:31 /test
```

I copied over the canonical example of using libhdfs in C from the [official documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html) -

```
#include "hdfs.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    hdfsFS fs = hdfsConnect("default", 0);
    // Also tested - hdfsConnect("127.0.0.1", 9000)
    const char* writePath = "/testfile.txt";
    hdfsFile writeFile = hdfsOpenFile(fs, writePath, O_WRONLY |O_CREAT, 0, 0, 0);
    if(!writeFile) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s for writing!\n", writePath);
          exit(-1);
    }
    char* buffer = "Hello, World!";
    tSize num_written_bytes = hdfsWrite(fs, writeFile, (void*)buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    if (hdfsFlush(fs, writeFile)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Failed to 'flush' %s\n", writePath);
          exit(-1);
    }
    hdfsCloseFile(fs, writeFile);
}
```

and I compile it "successfully" with -

```
gcc testlhdfs.c -I $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/include/ -L $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native -lhdfs
```

but I get an error when trying to run the executable -

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libhdfs.so.0.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't know why I am getting this error, when I can see that `libhdfs.so.0.0.0` exists in `$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native` -

```
reikdas@reikdas-HP-Pavilion-x360-Convertible-14-dh1xxx:~$ ls -l $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native
total 166640
drwxr-xr-x 2 reikdas reikdas      4096 Jun 15 01:44 examples
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas   1507316 Jun 15 01:13 libhadoop.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas   1741256 Jun 15 01:44 libhadooppipes.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 reikdas reikdas        18 Jun 15 01:13 libhadoop.so -> libhadoop.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 reikdas reikdas    803040 Jun 15 01:13 libhadoop.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas    754382 Jun 15 01:44 libhadooputils.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas    551556 Jun 15 01:18 libhdfs.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas 106522330 Jun 15 01:20 libhdfspp.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 reikdas reikdas        18 Jun 15 01:20 libhdfspp.so -> libhdfspp.so.0.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 reikdas reikdas  44375064 Jun 15 01:20 libhdfspp.so.0.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 reikdas reikdas        16 Jun 15 01:18 libhdfs.so -> libhdfs.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 reikdas reikdas    333648 Jun 15 01:18 libhdfs.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 reikdas reikdas  10029114 Jun 15 01:39 libnativetask.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 reikdas reikdas        22 Jun 15 01:39 libnativetask.so -> libnativetask.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 reikdas reikdas   3985736 Jun 15 01:39 libnativetask.so.1.0.0
```

My other environment variables are appropriately set as well -

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/reikdas/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

This might be a relevant configuration option that I have set in my `core-site.xml` file -

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000</value>
</property>
```

I'd really appreciate all the help I can get with fixing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try ldconfig $HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/native